# xpath retrieve data for first level only

Tags: html, xpath

Here is my HTML:

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <div id="articleBody">
                <p>text</p>
                <p>text2</p>
                <div>
                    <p>text3</p>
                    <p>text4</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my xpathL

```
    //div[@id="articleBody"]//p
```

This works fine, however I don't want any of the `p tags` within the second div.

How do I accomplish this? Also, I don't want it to be limited to just `div` elements to exclude.

**What I'm really looking for is to query and return only the first level p tags**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you are trying to grab. If its just the `p` tags under the given `div` you can just use:

```
//div[@id="articleBody"]/p
```

Given that you are using an `@id` attribute, there really should only be one `div` with that id, meaning that this will just grab any child `p` elements of that `div`.

When you use the `x//y` notation between two nodes, it grabs all the decendant `y` nodes from the given node `x`. You only want the direct children, hence using `x/y`.

Comment: I want to disclude the `p` tags that are in the second div. I.E. I need a query that only selects the `p` tags that are in the first level.

Comment: @jkushner Thats what this Xpath does.

Comment: No its accounting for the p tags that have `text3` and `text4` as content. I do not want those p tag contents. I think you didnt see that there is a second div.

Comment: @jkushner Then there your source XML document is different, you've not copied the XPath correctly, or your XSLT engine is buggy. The Xpath I've put, when applied the XML in your question **can only** retrieve the direct children of `<div id="articleBody">`.

Comment: the issue was a double slash instead of a single slash. thanks it works fine.